# What is a "gaussian" linear model?

Tags: linear-model, terminology

I saw the slides on https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-655-mathematical-statistics-spring-2016/lecture-notes/MIT18_655S16_LecNote19.pdf

The title of the slide is "gaussian linear models." But it seems the content is just for general linear model. Are the two equivalent?

Comment: The "Gaussian linear model" is a special case of the generalized linear model that just so happens to be ordinary least squares.

Comment: @AdamO I had a typo in my OP. I meant to type "general" instead of "generalized." Is the general linear model the same as the gaussian linear model? If so, then I don't think it's correct to say that a general linear model is OLS. OLS is just one (most popular) method to obtain a general model, but there are also other methods.

Comment: I see Kempthorne defines the general linear model on page 3 of the notes. It is the standard OLS model except that the error term is allowed to take any flavor -- not stated, but probably assuming IID and mean 0. The Gaussian linear model then would be the version with normally distributed (Gaussian) errors, where the OLS is the maximum likelihood estimator.

Comment: @AdamO Doesn’t the general linear model, by definition, assume normality of errors? If the error term is allowed to be anything, isn’t that a generalized linear model instead of a general model? The terminology confuses me.

Comment: Because there are so many resources on regression on the internet, it can be expected that definitions are often not perfectly aligned. Neither "General Linear Model" nor "Gaussian Linear Model" is a commonly used term. It's best to infer from context what exactly the author means.

Comment: Why are you still stuck on this? The definition is given on slide 3. If you're going to follow the course notes, you have to follow the professor's definitions; read them closely.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments by AdamO:

> I see Kempthorne defines the general linear model on page 3 of the
> notes. It is the standard OLS model except that the error term is
> allowed to take any flavor -- not stated, but probably assuming IID
> and mean 0. The Gaussian linear model then would be the version with
> normally distributed (Gaussian) errors, where the OLS is the maximum
> likelihood estimator.

Comment: Thank you for offering an answer.  I believe it misinterprets the slides, though, because later on there is a section *within this one* on models with Gaussian error terms that is referred to as *Normal* models.  "Gaussian linear model" most likely respects Gauss's contributions to OLS theory rather than referring to the error distribution.

Comment: @whuber Thanks - would you like to add that as a separate answer, or to edit this one to correct it?